Copy data from one database to another (.mdb to .accdb)
I have an old Access Database (.mdb) and need to copy the content to a new access file (.accdb)
The new file have the complete database structure exactly like the old file, it only needs the data.
It is not possible to read the data in the .mdb file as existing Access does not support it.
In addition this is a task that needs to be done regularly.
So I'm looking into a little vb.net program to do the task.
I thought of getting the data in to a dataset, then merge it into a dataset from the new file and save it.
I managed to read the data and merge it, but for some reason the data is not saved into the new database. No errors are thrown.
Any idea on what is wrong?
This is the code so far
Dim oldConn As OleDbConnection
   Dim OldCmd As OleDbCommand
   Dim OldDA As OleDbDataAdapter
   Dim newconn As OleDbConnection
   Dim newCmd As OleDbCommand
   Dim newDA As OleDbDataAdapter
   Dim oldDS As DataSet = New DataSet
   Dim newDS As DataSet = New DataSet
   Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder

   oldConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=oldfile.mdb;")
   oldConn.Open()
   OldCmd = New OleDbCommand()
   OldCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
   OldCmd.Connection = oldConn
   OldCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"
   OldDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(OldCmd)
   OldDA.Fill(oldDS, "TABLE1")

   newconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=newfile.accdb;")
   newconn.Open()
   newCmd = New OleDbCommand()
   newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
   newCmd.Connection = newconn
   newCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1"
   newDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(newCmd)
   builder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(newDA)
   newDA.Fill(newDS, "TABLE1")

   newDA.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand
   newDA.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand
   newDA.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand

   newDS.Merge(oldDS)
   newDA.Update(newDS, "TABLE1")


"It is not possible to read the data in the .mdb file as existing Access does not support it". How exactly did you determine that? If Access can't read an MDB file then I can only assume that it's corrupted, so you wo9udn't be able to read it from a VB app either.

@jmcilhinney: Current Access can only read Access files back to and including the format of Access 2000 (Jet 4). Thus, the format in question must be that of a previous version, Jet 1.x, 2,0 or 3.x.

@Gustav, I was not aware of that.

Is there really a need to merge the data in code? Can you not just Fill a DataTable and then Update the Database directly from that?

Quite sure Access 2010 can consume those mdb files. However, in place of code, I would consider launching Access, and creating a new blank database. You then try importing the table(s) - that should work - even with latest version of Access a import should still work. This approach would be much less work then attempting to write code. So, I would launch your version of Access. Create a new blank accDB database, and then try importing from the mdb file - see if that works.

@AlbertD.Kallal Access 2010 might be able to do that, but Access 2019 is not able to import anything from the old .mdb file. I just tried

The issue is that, by default, when you call Fill on a data adapter, it calls AcceptChanges on the DataTable. That means that every DataRow has a RowState of Unchanged, so there is nothing to insert when you call Update.
You need to set the AcceptChangesDuringFill property of the first data adapter to False. That way, all RowStates will remain Added and will be inserted when you call Update.
If all you want to do is to retrieve records from one database and insert them into the other then there's no need or point to retrieving data from the second database, just do what you actually need to. You only need one data adapter for that, because the SelectCommand and InsertCommand don't have to use the same connection, e.g.
Dim destinationConnection As New OleDbConnection(destinationConnectionString)
Dim insertCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES (@Column1, @Column2)",
                                      destinationConnection)

With insertCommand.Parameters
    .Add("@Column1", OleDbType.VarChar, 50, "Column1")
    .Add("@Column2", OleDbType.Intgeer, 0, "Column2")
End With

Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable",
                                    sourceConnectionString) With
                                   {.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False,
                                    .InsertCommand = insertCommand}
Dim table As New DataTable

adapter.Fill(table)
adapter.Update(table)

There's no need to open and close the connections yourself because the Fill and Update methods will do that. Because AcceptChanges is not called on Fill, all DataRows have a RowState of Added, so they will be inserted when you call Update.
Based on additional information provided in comments, it seems that the above example is not completely appropriate. Here's another example that will work and is still significantly simpler than your original attempt:
For Each tableName In tableNames
    Dim sourceAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM [{tableName}]", sourceConnectionString) With {.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False}
    Dim destinationAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter($"SELECT * FROM [{tableName}]", destinationConnectionString)
    Dim builder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(destinationAdapter) With {.QuotePrefix = "[", .QuoteSuffix = "]"}
    Dim table As New DataTable

    sourceAdapter.Fill(table)
    destinationAdapter.Update(table)
Next

That will loop over a list of table names and copy the contents of that table from a source database to a destination database. Note that I have set the QuotePrefix and QuoteSuffix properties of the command builder, in case there are some dodgy column names. If no column names contain any spaces or other special characters then that is unnecessary. The same goes for the brackets around the table name. Note also that there's no need or point to call GetInsertCommand, etc. That all happens automatically. You only need to get the commands if you intend to modify them manually, e.g. enrol them in a transaction.
If you try this and you still think no data is being inserted, do some debugging and get the values returned by Fill and Update, which are the number of records retrieved and saved respectively. They should match every time. If the former is non-zero and the latter is zero then there's something weird going on. If the latter is non-zero but you still think the data is not being saved then the issue is where and/or when you're looking for the data, which is actually quite common.

My problem is that I have to do this for about 50 different tables and I would really prefer not having to write all the INSERT commands and also not all the parameters as there are some of the tables that have A LOT of columns. This is the reason as why I tried to have the dataset and use the OleCommandBuilder.
I tried to set the AcceptChangesDuringFill to false in the first adapter, but still nothing is saved

@jpi76, then use a second data adapter and a command builder. Tat's barely more complex than my example and far simpler and more efficient than what you're doing. I'll post another example.

Looks and works great.
If I want to delete all data in each destination table before inserting the data from the sourcedestination how would I do this in your code?
